# constrOptim always returns starting values as optima, counts = 0, iterations = 1

Tags: r, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Something funny is going on with my constrained optimization, but I'm not sure what the problem is. The "optimized" values are always identically equal to my starting values. It says it's converged, but counts = 0 and iterations = 1. I'm not sure why.

```
options(scipens=15)

# Argument Vector ---------------------------------------------------------
# Starting values
args <- c(3553.13, 727.48)

# Revenue Formula ---------------------------------------------------------
intercept <- -4.5315
p_elast   <- -.065
o_elast   <-  .066
leads     <- 20000

rev_fn <- function(args){
  CR       <- exp(intercept + (p_elast*log(args[1])) + (o_elast*log(args[2])))
  price    <- args[1]-args[2]   # charges - offer amount
  quantity <- leads*CR          # leads * CR
  revenue  <- price*quantity

  return(revenue)
}

rev_fn(args)

# Gradient Function -------------------------------------------------------  
gr <- function(args){
        c(leads * (exp(intercept + (p_elast * log(args[1])) + (o_elast *
          log(args[2]))) * (p_elast * (1/args[1]))),
          leads * (exp(intercept + (p_elast * log(args[1])) + (o_elast *
            log(args[2]))) * (o_elast * (1/args[2])))
        )
}

# Constrained Optimization ------------------------------------------------
# Constraints
# 1. Gross price > 0
# 2. Offer > 0
# 3. Gross price > offer

constraint_matrix     <- matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,-1),ncol=2)
constraint_vector     <- c(0,0,0)

# Note: feasible region =  ui %*% theta - ci >= 0
constrOptim(theta   = c(args[1], # gross price
                        args[2]  # offer amount
                        ),
            f       = rev_fn,
            grad    = gr,
            ui      = constraint_matrix, # constraint matrix (k x p)
            ci      = constraint_vector, # constraint vector of length k
            control = list(fnscale = -1) # maximization
            )
```

> ```
> $par
> [1] 3553.13  727.48
>
> $value
> [1] 552374.2
>
> $counts
> [1] 0
>
> $convergence
> [1] 0
>
> $message
> NULL
>
> $outer.iterations
> [1] 1
>
> $barrier.value
> [1] 4.919046
> ```

Comment: I would suggest you to describe the problem with much more words, also you could add a pseudo-code/algorithm or a list of mathematical expressions that you try to evaluate so that everyone could read the code and possibly find the bug, no matter does one know R or not.

Comment: (1) Can you check the gradients. It seems the sign is wrong (if multiplied by -1 things are moving). (2) Even then, I believe the model will not converge. I suspect the model is unbounded.